# Syntax for checking if value in string

Tags: python

Im trying to do a simple check if there is 3 specific value in a string. If there is, the statement should return nothing, instead of save.

Here is my code, but I think the syntax is wrong:

```
if not ('2239687' or '2238484' or '2239440') in user_id:
    #The user is not admin, save the user
    web_user.save()
```

To elaborate, I want it to test if `user_id` is "2239687" or "2238484" or "2239440" (and not, for example, "002239440"). If the user_id is one of those three values (and ONLY those three values), the statement should return false.

Comment: If you wanna see what's happening: http://www.diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/and_or.html

Comment: To clarify, 1) "user_id" is a string, right? 2) should it return True if user_id = `99922396879999`?

Comment: Yes user_id should be a string. All other values should return True, but these three values should return False. Is there some way I can test if the user_id is a string or not?

Comment: @Garreth00: now I'm confused. Are you testing if `user_id` _contains_ "2239687" (or 2238484 or 2239440) - as in "99922396879999" - or if it's _equal_ to "2239687" (or 2238484 or 2239440)?

Comment: @thg435: I want it to test if user_id is "2239687" or "2238484" or "2239440" (and not "002239440") If the user_id is one of those three values (and ONLY those three values), the statement should return false

Comment: @Garreth00: ok, I've edited the post to make the point clear.

Answer (score 2):

One more option:

```
if not any(idx in user_id for idx in ('2239687' ,'2238484' , '2239440')):
    # do something
```

Comment: This should not be used in this case

Comment: @jamylak yes, maybe you are right, then just a case to know that 'any' function exists

Comment: @glglgl i know - but each ohe us can only suppose what type of comparison he need - the option here is 'any' function not a comparison type

Comment: `id` is a built-in function. Don't use it as a variable name.

Answer (score 2):

```
if not any(x in user_id for x in ('2239687', '2238484', '2239440')):
    #The user is not admin, save the user
    web_user.save()
```

This checks whether none of the three string is present within `user_id`.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
if user_id not in ('2239687' ,'2238484' , '2239440'):
```

Or

```
if not user_id in ('2239687' ,'2238484' , '2239440'):
```

Comment: This seems right, but the "save" does still gets executed me (I'm 2239687).

Comment: @Garreth00 str(2239687) not in ('2239687' ,'2238484' , '2239440') try like this,

Comment: Correct me but i always thought that 'not user_id in ('2239687' ,'2238484' , '2239440'):' is not very pythonic?